# A person suggested horrible edits to an old question of mine and it got accepted

Tags: support, suggested-edits, revision-history

A few hours ago, somebody suggested edits to a question a posted in 2010. He removed parts of the original question so it doesn't make sense any longer, and he removed all code formatting. The most bizarre thing is that the edit got accepted by more than one person.

It's obvious that the contributors who approved the edit didn't even look at it, else it would not have been approved.

What does one do in this situation?

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2886272/revisions

Comment: You can roll the edit back to the revision you want.

Comment: So... The original suggested edit didn't remove your formatting... One of the reviewers did! Which is even worse, in my mind. You should rollback the edit. In the revisions, click "rollback" on the revision you want your post set back to. (It'll be on the left side, along with "Source" and "Link")

Comment: Fantastic thanks guys - I didn't see that option. It's rolled back now.

Comment: @ConstantMeiring Now you even got a [badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/4/cleanup) for this!

Comment: @Rizier123 woo! \:D/

Comment: @Mistalis This is a beautiful example of a signpost duplicate.

Comment: @Mistalis Yes, it might help people who do not know to specifically search for rolling back edits. :)

Comment: You can/should also flag the post for moderator attention, asking for the robo-reviewers who approved revision 2 to be suspended from reviewing.

Comment: @andrew It appears that revision 2 was *correct*. The problem was revision 3, and nobody reviewed that. It was one of the reviewers who clicked "Improve Edit".

Comment: @AndrewMedico - This has been handled.

Comment: @BradLarson killed him.